Minor Revision Response Waiting Period
I've submitted a paper to a Q2 journal of economics after which I've got a response 5 months later recommending minor revision. I have then submitted the revised manuscript which I believe has incorporated the necessary changes outlined by the reviewers. However, it's been approximately 6 weeks since I last submitted the revised manuscript and the current status is still "Awaiting Reviewer Scores". I really don't know how to interpret the long waiting period knowing that many say a response after a minor revision submission is usually expected to be in less than 4 weeks or even 2 weeks.

The paper likely went back out to reviewers. Have patience.

Sorry, no one on the internet can tell you what you want to know. See the above post for some discussion on this topic.

It can always happen that invited reviewers don't reply to invitations or don't deliver a review that they promised, leading to delay. Variance of waiting times is huge and 6 weeks is by no means particularly long (unless it's a journal that values speed over quality, for which reasons it will quite likely be of low quality because reviewers may be unqualified and/or pressured into not taking time to thinking things through properly).
